# How to disable ssl verification on provider side for Pact Broker?

Tags: ssl, pact-net

I'm trying to implement pact verification on provider side using pact-net v4.5.0.0 or v5.0 beta. Here is my code for this:

```
using var verifier = new PactVerifier();
verifier.ServiceProvider("CampaignFinder API", new Uri(PactServiceUri))
    .WithPactBrokerSource(new Uri("https://pact-broker-pact.apps.ocpdoa.akbank.com"))
    .WithSslVerificationDisabled()
    .WithProviderStateUrl(new Uri($"{PactServiceUri}/provider-states"))
    .Verify();
```

But it fails with this error:

```
1) Failed to load pact - Could not load pacts from the pact broker 'https://pact-broker-pact.apps.ocpdoa.akbank.com/'


There were 1 pact failures

Verifier Logs
-------------
2023-12-12T13:42:26.942303Z  INFO ThreadId(09) pact_verifier::pact_broker: Fetching path '/' from pact broker
2023-12-12T13:42:26.974295Z  WARN ThreadId(09) rustls::conn: Sending fatal alert BadCertificate    
2023-12-12T13:42:26.974776Z ERROR ThreadId(09) pact_verifier: Failed to load pact - [31mCould not load pacts from the pact broker 'https://pact-broker-pact.apps.ocpdoa.akbank.com/'[0m
2023-12-12T13:42:26.974834Z  WARN ThreadId(09) pact_matching::metrics: 

Please note:
We are tracking events anonymously to gather important usage statistics like Pact version and operating system. To disable tracking, set the 'PACT_DO_NOT_TRACK' environment variable to 'true'.
```

v5.0 log does not state the root cause of the problem but I guess it is the same ssl error:

```
Failures:

1) Failed to load pact - Could not load pacts from the pact broker 'https://pact-broker-pact.apps.ocpdoa.akbank.com/'


There were 1 pact failures

Verifier Logs
-------------
2023-12-14T08:39:30.795018Z  INFO ThreadId(09) pact_verifier::pact_broker: Fetching path '/' from pact broker
2023-12-14T08:39:30.826714Z ERROR ThreadId(09) pact_verifier: Failed to load pact - [31mCould not load pacts from the pact broker 'https://pact-broker-pact.apps.ocpdoa.akbank.com/'[0m
2023-12-14T08:39:30.826831Z  WARN ThreadId(09) pact_matching::metrics: 

Please note:
We are tracking events anonymously to gather important usage statistics like Pact version and operating system. To disable tracking, set the 'PACT_DO_NOT_TRACK' environment variable to 'true'.
```

Our pact-broker is using a self signed certiciface, I guess this is the cause of the error.

Why does .WithSslVerificationDisabled() call have no effect? When I import the certificate to my computer's trust store, I can run the test succesfully. However I'd like to disable ssl verification as this may cause problems in CI/CD.

Please advise how to disable ssl check.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [ffi bug](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-reference/issues/387). As a temporary solution, I can suggest to use a reverse-proxy in ci (for example, nginx or traefik), and in tests make a call to the proxy via http and redirect this call to https to the broker.